# Updating variable imported from other Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a variable (a list) in a Python script A and import it in script B, like so:

```
from app import keywords
```

At some point script A updates the variable (appends list items), but while script B is running, the variable doesn't update.

I've tried with reload but then I get following error message: TypeError: reload() argument must be a module

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't import variables. You import *modules*. In this case, you imported a module, then *created a new variable called `keywords`* that refers to the same object, but is an independent variable. Just like if you had done `import app` then `keywords = app.keywords`. If you want to modify a global variable in a module (really bad practice, generally) you can use `import app` then `app.keywords = whatever`

Comment: Note, however, that if you really mutated the list, it **should** still be visible by both variables, so you **really** must provide a [mcve] when you say: "At some point script A updates the variable (appends list items), "